# Determining open loop gain

Tags: feedback

What would be the gain of the A circuit (A unit in feedback) in the following circuit? First, what would be B? Merely the short connecting Vo and Q2?[image]

Comment: You should show some work you have done on this.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was only asking about the feedback element and the \$A\$ feedback unit. I first performed the DC analysis of course but that's not very relevant to my question, is it? What work would you like me to show? Please clarify. My work, or attempt rather, was guessing that the feedback would be the wire connecting Vo and the gate of Q2.

Comment: Your gain is of several parts: (1) diffpair GM * diode_load resistance; (2) Q4 current mirror (3X the diode) with its GM, into its rout (Av = gm4 * rout4); (3) gain~~1 with Q5

Comment: @analogsystemsrf But don't I first need to determine what the feedback is and find R11 and R22, its input and output resistances?

Comment: The closed loop gain will be around 1 and feedback factor is 1.

Comment: @G36 May I do this?: \$A=\frac{g_{m5}r_{o5}}{g_{m5}r_{o5}+1} \cdot -g_{m4}r_{o4} \cdot -g_{m1} (1/g_{m3}||r_{o3})\$, since \$R_{11}=0,R_{22}=inf.\$. This yields \$A_f=A/(1+AB)=0.99\$. Does that seem correct to you?

Comment: why 1/gm3||ro3 ?

Comment: @G36 Why wouldn't that be the overall resistance "seen" from the source of Q5. Should it be only r03? Is the rest correct?